# Autosys failing a job if the dependent job doesnot complete/success before a particular time

Tags: autosys

Autosys job retail_daily_job runs at 8:00 GMT. It is dependent on success of runner_daily_job.
Condition is If runner_daily_job is not success by 7:30 GMT, then status of retail_daily_job should be made to fail.i.e retail_daily_job should fail.

How to do this in autosys? what is the command to be used in jil file?

Thanks and Regards,
Simi

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to do. Autosys doesn't support a negation condition for example NOT SUCCESS. I would try creating a job that would run at 0730 that would change the status of the retail_daily_job job to FAILURE if the runner_daily_job is FAILURE or TERMINATED or RUNNING.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with clmccomas, not easy due to lack of certain operators.

We get around this by having our jobs create "status" files that other jobs can reference if need be. I've found that trying to parse/depend on output from autorep can be troublesome but is also doable. So we usually have a job status directory and create dated folders

/yyyymmdd/jobname_

The your command job would check the existing status file that's there. Often you may only want to write the status on completion.

The suggestion of having a job to alter statuses might work out well too.

Answer (score 0):

Itseems like you are making the situation a bit complex.

If you want retail_daily_job to run based on the success of runner_daily_job, then simply put the condition as success(runner_daily_job).

So as you said if runner_daily_job is not success by 7:30 GMT (which means failure), then automatically the status of retail_daily_job will become to fail.

Hope this clarifies your question.